# Java swing tabbed pane add tab exception

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

I have a Java swing application that creates and displays a tabbedpane and creates an update thread. The update thread when triggered needs to add a set of tabs with content but I am getting an exception now and again "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Is this something to do with adding tabs in a different thread? If so how do I add a tab to it in a thread safe way please??

Here is an example application that illustrates the problem

```
public class Example extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private final JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private final Rectangle bounds;

    public Example() {
        super("Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
        setBounds(bounds);
        setLayout(null);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setBounds(bounds);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(null);
        jp.setBounds(bounds);
        jp.add(tabbedPane);
        add(jp);

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                tabbedPane.addTab("NEW" + i, new JPanel());
                repaint();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: That runnable would best be replaced by a `javax.swing.Timer`.  The GUI should also be started on the EDT.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: This is likely a threading issue. See Andrew's comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is not thread safe...

This means that you should never try to create or modify the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The likely issue is you've run into some kind of race condition.  Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    private final JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private final Rectangle bounds;

    public Example() {
        super("Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
        setBounds(bounds);
//      setLayout(null);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.setBounds(bounds);

//      JPanel jp = new JPanel();
//      jp.setLayout(null);
//      jp.setBounds(bounds);
//      jp.add(tabbedPane);
//      add(jp);

        add(tabbedPane);

        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    tabbedPane.addTab("NEW" + tabbedPane.getTabCount(), new JPanel());
                }
                tabbedPane.revalidate();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Example e = new Example();
                e.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: This certainly fixes the issue thanks, however if I want to add and remove tabs at will from another thread do I have to kick off timer threads each time?

Comment: It depends. But most likely, you could get away with doing with one time, since the updates will occur from within the EDT (one at a time) anyway

Comment: *"..do I have to kick off timer threads each time?"*  A call from another thread can be wrapped in a `EventQueue.invokeLater(..)` to ensure it is done on the EDT.  One advantage of using a Swing `Timer` is that any GUI changes made are already on the EDT.

Comment: Then we just run into timing issues where you could try and remove a tab before it exists :D